# Find differences between files only on lines with specific words

Tags: linux, diff

I understand to find the differences between files you would use

```
diff *file1 file2*
```

But say you only wanted to know the differences between the two files on lines that contained a specific word, say the word "linux" for example. How would you write the command for that?  Would it be something like:

```
diff [linux] *file1 file2*
```

Or would you even use diff at all for this command?

Comment: Did you read the `man`(ual)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below command to find the diff between two files and filter the string "linux" diff

```
diff file1 file2 | grep 'linux' -B1 -A2
```

Answer (score 0):

To find a particular pattern in a file for example, you would want to use the `grep` command. 
Basically, the grep command searches the given input files for lines containing a match or a text string.
For example:

```
grep "text string to search" insert_the_folder_containing_the_desired_files
```

To read more about the grep command, type `man grep` on the command line.
man means manual and the next word is the program you wish to open the manual for.